# A formula about polynomials: $x^{n^i-1}-1=(x^s-1)\prod_{j=1}^r(x^{2^{j-1}s}+1)$, where $n^i-1=2^rs$

Tags: polynomials

$x^{n^i-1}-1=(x^s-1)\prod_{j=1}^r(x^{2^{j-1}s}+1)$, where 
$n^i-1=2^rs$. Also, the factors on the right side are relatively prime polynomials.

I found this formula on Grantham's "Frobenius Pseudoprimes". There is no explanation or reference to one. I would like to find a proof, or at least a reference to it.

So far the only thing I could prove was that each factor in the right side divides the left side, and that the two sides are monic polynomials of the same degree.

Comment: Relatively prime as polynomials, presumably?

Comment: Yeah. I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Given **any** $m=2^rs$, then $$x^m-1=\left(x^s-1\right)\prod_{j=0}^{r-1} \left(x^{2^js}+1\right)$$

Prove first for $s=1$, then for arbitrary $s$, you can substitute $x=y^s$ into the simpler case.

You prove the case $s=1$ by induction on $r$, starting at $r=0$:

$$x^{1}-1 = (x^1-1)$$

I'll leave the induction step to you.

Or you can check out [this prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321262/why-is-232-1-212212412812161) for the case $s=1$ and the specific case $x=2$.

For the second part, first note that if $n<m$ then $x^{2^n}-1\mid x^{2^{m-1}}-1$. So any prime divisor of $x^{2^n}-1$ and $x^{2^{m-1}}+1$ would have to divide $2$, and hence be a constant polynomial.

But that means that $x^{2^{n-1}}+1$ has no common factor with $x^{2^{n-1}}+1$, since $x^{2^{n-1}}+1\mid x^{2^n}-1$.

The same argument shows that $x^{2^{n-1}}+1$ has no common factors with $x^{2^{m-1}}+1$.

Comment: Thanks, I proved the equality, but still I can't see the relatively primes statement.

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. Unfortunately, I have to run out, so hopefully, somebody else can write a fuller proof.